# Cloudflare DNS: Can't change IP address

Tags: dns, ip-address, cloudflare

After moving to the new server, for sure, I need to change the DNS settings at Cloudflare to the new server IP address.
Cloudflare control panel can show the new ip address that I've setup, but when doing some dig command, the ip address returned still the old one. Although I already request directly to the ns specified by Cloudflare.

here is my dig command:
**dig thedomain.tld @cfns.ns.cloudflare.com**

Strangely, when I pause the cloudflare, I can see the new ip from dig command above.
any hint to solve that ?

Comment: impossible to diagnose - domain and auth servers as given in question don't exist. If that's the actual problem: try again using correct names for those.

Answer (score 0):

It actually sounds like you may be running into some recursive DNS caching issues. We push out IP changes that are made in your DNS settings very quickly (minutes or less), but it may take a little longer to push out everywhere.